# variable not updating vb.net

Tags: vb.net, global-variables, public

[image]

After one scan the variable `plc` restores the default values.
how i can keep the last values introduced?

i'm using "GetSetting" and  "SaveSetting" functions like the example below.

```
    Private Sub TxtBox_IPAdress_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 
       SaveSetting(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, "DadosGerais", "PLC1_IP", TxtBox_IPAdress.Text)
    End Sub
```

code:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports S7.Net

Module GlobalVar

    '  Public PLC As Plc
    ' Public Errorlist As exceptionCode


    Public Valor_do_loop_pre_defenido As Integer = 100    'valor médio pretendido para o tempo de ciclo/loop da aplicação 


    Public hhextracao As String '= "hh"
    Public mmextracao As String '= "mm"
    Public ssextracao As String '= "ss"
    Public thisDay As String '= Date.Now.ToString("dd")
    Public thisMonth As String '= Date.Now.ToString("MM")
    Public thisYear As String '= Date.Now.ToString("yyyy")
    Public thisHour As String '= Date.Now.ToString("HH")
    Public thisMinute As String '= Date.Now.ToString("mm")
    Public thisSec As String '= Date.Now.ToString("ss")
    Public PLC1_IP As String
    Public PLC1_Rack As Integer
    Public PLC1_Slot As Integer
    Public Select_PLC1_Type As Integer
    Public PLC1_Type As CpuType
    Public PLC1 As New Plc(PLC1_Type, PLC1_IP, PLC1_Rack, PLC1_Slot)
    Public test1 As Boolean
    Public test1_in As Boolean
    Public test1_out As Boolean
    Public Sub Settings_Read()



        PLC1_IP = GetSetting(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, "DadosGerais", "PLC1_IP", "192.168.0.10")
        PLC1_Rack = GetSetting(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, "DadosGerais", "PLC1_Rack", "0")
        PLC1_Slot = GetSetting(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, "DadosGerais", "PLC1_Slot", "1")
        Select_PLC1_Type = GetSetting(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, "DadosGerais", "Select_PLC1_Type", "3")

        Select Case Select_PLC1_Type
            Case 0
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S7200
            Case 1
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S7300
            Case 2
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S7400
            Case 3
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S71200
            Case 4
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S71500
            Case 5
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S7200Smart
            Case 6
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.Logo0BA8
            Case Else 'default
                PLC1_Type = CpuType.S7300
                '       ComboBox_CPUType.SelectedIndex = ComboBox_CPUType_SelectedIndex
        End Select

        ' Dim PLC As New Plc(PLC1_Type, PLC1_IP, PLC1_Rack, PLC1_Slot)
        ' PLC1 = PLC


    End Sub


End Module
```

The error I am receiving is: system.typeinitializationexception: the type initializer for 'siemensConnext.globalvar' threw an exception
Inner exception: Argument exception: IP address must be valid. Parameter: ip
shows the next error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP3X2.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as text, formatted as code. We can't copy text from a picture.

Comment: jmcilhinney, thanks.
I already changed it

Answer (score 0):

dont see event handler in your code so textchanged nether triggered. change sub declaration as :

```
Private Sub TxtBox_IPAdress_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtBox_IPAdress.TextChanged
```

you can use debugger to fix this kind of problem by stopping on sub call.

Comment: If he isn't using auto hook up this may not matter. He may be declaring the sub name in his markup, however if that is the case, that sub should be protected instead of private, which may be a whole other issue itself.